# format explode data after first piece with foreach

Tags: php, foreach, explode

What I have is this array:

```
$l = "apple,orange,tomato,banana,carrot,celery";
```

What i'm trying to do is something along these lines:

```
apple OR orange OR tomato OR banana OR carrot OR celery
```

I've gotten this far:

```
$l = explode(",", $l);
if (count($l) > 1){
    foreach ($l as $s){
        echo " OR " . $s;
    }
}
```

Doing it this way puts OR in front of all the pieces of the array:

```
OR apple OR orange OR tomato OR banana OR carrot OR celery
```

What would be the proper way to count the first piece, then append to all the additional pieces?

Comment: Try `implode()` to glue the array back together.

Comment: One should really try to learn how to use the [PHP manual](http://uk.php.net/), you can even [download an offline](http://uk.php.net/download-docs.php) version of it.

Comment: "to count the first piece" - count what ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
$array = explode(",", $l);
echo implode(" OR ", $array);
```

Or in one liner:

```
echo implode(" OR ", explode(",", $l));
```

Comment: also, a `trim($string,', ')` won't hurt. 
Maybe a bit crazy, `$string=preg_replace('/,{2,}/ix', ',', $string);` -- just for fun :)

Answer (score 4):

Use str_replace:

```
$string = 'oranges,apples,pineapple';

echo str_replace(',', ' OR ', $string);

// Outputs: oranges OR apples OR pineapple
```

Answer (score 1):

one line skill

```
$array = implode (' OR ', explode (',', $array));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try with this :)

```
echo preg_replace('/,/', " OR ", "apple,orange,tomato,banana,carrot,celery");
```

Comment: Why are you using `[.,]` instead of `,` ?

Answer (score 0):

or in case you want to treat the information :

```
$pieces = explode (',', $array);

$result = '';
$i = 0;
foreach ($pieces as $p) {
   $i++;

   if ($p === 'banana') // in case you hate banana
      continue;

   $result .= $p;

   if ($i != count($pieces))
      $result .= ' OR ';
}
```